# SCP use remote server variable

Tags: variables, unix, scp

I'm writing a script trying to both scp files to and from a remote server, and want to use the remote server variable within the script rather than hardcode the directory into the script, as this will be used in different environments with different paths.

So for example the hardcoded version to fetch a file ...

*scp user@remotehost:/userbase/filefolder/file1 .*

but lets say on the remote host "userbase" was set as a $BASEHOME variable. I know a standard

*scp user@remotehost:$BASEHOME/filefolder/file1 .*

won't work as it tries to evaluate $BASEHOME on the host sending the scp

I had a look around and its been suggested online that something similar to the following may work

*scp user@remotehost:$(ssh user@remotehost "echo \$BASEHOME")/filefolder/file1 .*

But this errors - I tried printf instead of echo, single quotes and no \before $BASEHOME but none work, with errors similar to the following appearing (as if its not picking up the variable)

*scp: /filefolder/file1: No such file or directory*

Is it possible to use a remote variable when scp'ing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to use remote shell variables with `scp`.

Workaround 1: get the remote variable once and reuse it later:

```
BASEHOME=$(ssh user@remotehost 'echo $BASEHOME')
scp user@remotehost:$BASEHOME/filefolder/file1 .
```

Workaround 2: `cat` the file on the remote side and redirect to local file:

```
ssh user@remotehost 'cat $BASEHOME/filefolder/file1' > file1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it didn't quite work for me but got me on the right track

The command I've ended up using goes a little something like this;

BASEHOME=$(ssh -t user@remotehost ". ~/.profile > /dev/null ; echo \$BASEHOME") 

I had to ssh -t and call the .profile and redirect to /dev/null so all the output didn't end up in the variable

Comment: @user2920657 Thanks, your comment helped a lot. I also had to explicitly source my profile first.